# Как вывести данные из БД, при определённом значении и временем, не позже чем 10 мин.?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

Подскажите, как вывести данные из БД, при значении «1» в столбце «example», и временем, не позже чем 10 мин.? То есть по истечении этого времени запись исчезает из поля зрения сайта.

При добавлении поста записывается время в таблицу —

```
$post->timepublic = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Пример вывода поста (без фильтра по времени)

```
$posts = R::findAll('posts', 'active = 1');
foreach ($posts as $post) {
echo '<strong>Head:</strong> ', $post->head;
echo '<br><strong>Desc:</strong> ', $post->desc;
```

Comment: *временем, не позже чем 10 мин.?* Добавьте ещё одно выражение в условия отбора. `timepublic > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE`

Comment: @Akina таким образом — ('posts', 'timepublic = ? AND active = ?', ['CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE'], 1]); ?